# Outputing error messages on a form generated through Javascript dynamically with jQuery.validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

It seems that the validate function doesn't work when the form is dynamically generated through Javascript. The validation seems to work, but the error messages aren't displaying. Is there a reason for this and is there any workaround?

I am using this and I realized that this code works when the form is hardcoded and doesn't work when the code is generated through javascript.

```
   $('#some-form').validate({
        rules: {
            'feature1': {
                min: 1,
                required: true
            },
            'feature2': {
                min: 1
            },
        },
        messages: {
            'feature1': {
                min: "error1",
                required: "error2"
            },
            'feature2': {
                min: "error3"
            },
        }
});
```

There might be some syntax error, because I didn't paste the code.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example including the relevant HTML markup of the `form` as well as the code that creates/inserts the `form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the validate function doesn't work when the form is dynamically generated through JavaScript.

It works perfectly fine if you call `.validate()` *after* the form is created.

You cannot attach the `.validate()` method to a form that does not yet exist in the DOM... pretty standard stuff.

> The validation seems to work, but the error messages aren't displaying.

Impossible.  If you don't see error messages, then the validation plugin is not working.

> Is there a reason for this and is there any workaround?

As explained above.  When the `form` is dynamically generated, you can only attach `.validate()` to it immediately ***after*** the form is created.

```
// code that dynamically creates '#some-form' goes here

    $('#content').html('<form id="some-form">...</form>');

// then initialize the plugin on '#some-form' here

    $('#some-form').validate({ // initialize plugin
        ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ptj9gptr/**

---

**EDIT:**

For fields that are created dynamically ***after*** after `.validate()` is called (*same as after plugin is initialized*), you would use [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to add and remove rules dynamically.

Comment: What if you are adding fields dynamically to the form? Can the plugin still validate properly?

Comment: @ajax, dynamically adding fields is an entirely different question.  However, the developer provides a method for this too.  See edited answer.